# On Kato's proof that first Iwasawa cohomology is free

Tags: number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

In Kato's *$p$-adic Hodge Theory and Values of Zeta Functions of Modular Forms*, Kato proves in 13.8 that the first Iwasawa cohomology:
$$\mathbf{H}^1(T):=\varprojlim_n H^1(\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_{p^n}, 1/p],T)$$
is free of rank one under the hypothesis that the residual Galois representation:
$$T/\mathcal{m}_\lambda T$$
is irreducible.
In particular Kato uses the fact that given a maximal ideal $(x,y)$ in $\Lambda$,
$$\Lambda/(x,y)\cong \mathcal{O}_\lambda/\mathfrak{m}_\lambda(r)$$
where $(r)$ denotes some Tate twist. I have a number of questions about this.

1. Is the integer $r$ in this statement independent of the choice of $x,y$?
2. If it is independent, then is it known which integer $r$ occurs here? (it is unclear to me how anything but the trivial representation could occur here)
3. Could Kato sharpen his hypothesis from "$T/\mathcal{m}_\lambda T$ is irreducible" to "the $r$-th Tate twist of the trivial character does not occur in $T/\mathcal{m}_\lambda T$", or is there something more technical to the proof that I'm missing?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I am not sure why people vote to close this question. Those questions seem tightly connected to each other. Also, this person is new to this platform, it would be nice to leave a short comment to tell them how to improve their question in your opinion if you decide after all to vote to close.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven: I totally agree with you. Somehow, asking questions regarding proofs is somehow a closeable post? I can't imagine why someone would have issue with such a question.

Comment: @Moo It seems you don't have just cowtastic ears, but also eyes (love your bio) :D I think it might be that the amount of reputation of the OP encourages rude behaviour, it's a bit sad.